# Como escrever tachado?

Tags: suporte, formatação

Como faço para escrever "**tachado**" no SO?

Escrever do jeito que fica com um risco no meio das letras.

Vi em alguns sites que seria usando `~~assim~~`, mas como dá para ver, aqui não funcionou.

**Edit:** No comentário da p/ fazer também?

testei no comentário dessa pergunta e não funcionou.

Comment: E agora que temos duas respostas que me atende, posso escolher as duas ? rsrsrsr

Comment: No comentário da p/ fazer também ? <s>teste</s> <strike>teste</strike>

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Além da tag `<strike>` citada pelo [@Math](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4020/3635) você também pode utilizar uma tag mais rápida `<s>...</s>`

Com usar:

```html
<s>Exemplo</s>
```

Resultado:

> <s>Exemplo</s>

### Outras formatações

Para visualizar a Ajuda/Dicas sobre outras formatações, clique no `?` e note que clicando em `HTML`, irá falar sobre o `<strike>`:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Note que também ele informa:

> Se precisar fazer algo com o qual o markdown não pode lidar, use HTML. [Observe que oferecemos suporte apenas a um subconjunto de HTML muito estrito!](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1777/what-html-tags-are-allowed-on-stack-exchange-sites)

| Tag | Descrição |
| --- | --- |
| `<a>` | Hiperlink ou âncora. |
| `<b>` | Negrito, porém é preferido usar `<h1>`-`<h3>`, `<em>` e `<strong>`. |
| `<blockquote>` | Especifica uma seção como uma citação de outro local. |
| `<code>` | Para pedaços de código. |
| `<del>` | Usado para indicar modificações (semelhante ao `<s>`). |
| `<dd>` | Item da lista descritiva `<dl>`. |
| `<dl>` | Lista descritiva. |
| `<dt>` | Título da lista descritiva `<dl>`. |
| `<em>` | Ênfase. |
| `<h1>`, `<h2>`, `<h3>` | Títulos. |
| `<i>` | Itálico. |
| `<img>` | Imagem/foto. |
| `<kbd>` | Representa teclas do teclado do usuário. |
| `<li>` | Item de uma lista ordenada `<ol>` ou não ordenada `<ul>`. |
| `<ul>` | Lista não-ordenada. |
| `<ol>` | Lista ordenada. |
| `<p>` | Parágrafo. |
| `<pre>` | Mostra texto com tamanho fixo em sem mudanças na quebra de linhas. |
| `<s>` | Rasurado/tachado. |
| `<sup>` | Texto sobrescrito, aparece meio caractere acima da linha de base. Usado para notas de rodapé e outras formatação. |
| `<sub>` | Texto subscrito, aparece meio caractere abaixo da linha de base. |
| `<strong>` | Negrito. Usado para texto/palavra com importância. |
| `<strike>` | Esta tag está em desuso, ao invés dela use `<del>`. |
| `<br>` | Quebra de linha. |
| `<hr>` | Define uma mudança temática no conteúdo, geralmente através de uma linha horizontal. |

Outras tags são desabilitadas (até mesmo a tag `<table>`)

### Atributos permitidos

- Atributos para tag `<img>`

  Evite larguras maior que 90%, pois isto prejudica visualizar no site mobile.

  A ordem dos atributos é importante, se usar height antes de width por exemplo, isto será "escapado/removido".

  Ordem de uso:

  ```html
  src=""
  width="" (no máximo 999; não use 'px')
  height="" (no máximo 999; não use 'px')
  alt=""
  title=""
  ```
- Atributos para tag `<a>`:

  ```html
  href=""
  title=""
  ```

Fontes:

- [What HTML tags are allowed on Stack Exchange sites?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/135909/198279)
- [Ajuda do markdown](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/editing-help)

### Markdown no chat

No chat para usarmos o tachado, fazemos assim `---Olá---`, segue a lista do markdown:

| Sintaxe | Descrição |
| --- | --- |
| `*italic*` ou `_italic_` | Itálico |
| `**bold**` ou `__bold__` | Negrito |
| `\`code`` | Para pedaços de código. |
| `---strikeout---` | Texto tachado |
| `[texto](http://site.com "titulo opicional")` | Hiperlink ou âncora. |

Para encontrar mais dicas no chat clique em *Help*:

[image: Help no chat]

Comment: Dessa eu não sabia, muito mais econômico.. pegue meu +1 agora

Comment: Também desconhecia +1

Comment: Eu entendi bem? Então existem alguns códigos que não estão na "documentação" de ajuda da formatação? A opção de `editar` como o Math falou é uma ótima ideia.

Comment: @Florida na verdade está sim documentado, só não está tão acessivel. Editei a resposta.

Answer (score 9):

Você precisar usar a marcação `<strike>` e fechá-la com `</strike>`

Fonte:

```
<strike>Exemplo</strike>
```

Resultado:

> <strike>Exemplo</strike>

Além disso, caso você encontre alguma publicação aqui nos sites da rede Stack Exchange você tem a opção de ver o código fonte de uma publicação para saber como algo foi feito, clicando em `editar` para analisá-lo.

Comment: obrigado Math! Era isso mesmo

Comment: Math escolhi a resposta do @GuilhermNascimento não fica triste viu, você já ganhou as eleições já tem motivos de sobra p/ ficar alegre =)

Comment: @SneepSNinjA hahaha, tranquilo, até eu escolheria a dele ;-)