# Implementar o tachado diretamente no Markdown

Tags: novo-recurso

Perguntas relacionadas:

- [Como escrever tachado?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/4019/)
- [Como escrever tachado em comentarios](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/4773/)
- [novo recurso - Tachado nos comentários](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/4784/)

Como todas as outras postagens de tachado **não entraram no que eu acho que é o cerne da questão**, segue:

Podemos ter tachado no Markdown? É um recurso usado em várias perguntas e respostas, e um jeito elegante de mostrar um edit em casos onde é importante as pessoas notarem que ocorreu (por exemplo, uma correção ou referência feita e editada depois de uma mudança no contexto da postagem, que outra pessoa já referenciou).

Hoje o tachado só pode ser usado com tags HTML, e apesar de o HTML ser permitido parcialmente no Markdown, acho conceitualmente errado. Por mim, o markdown simplesmente não aceitaria HTML.

Como o Skype faz? assim: ~este texto é tachado~. O resultado é <s>este texto é tachado</s>. Não vejo motivo para não termos (já que a comunidade usa mesmo).

Notar que o MarkDown do SO ja é customizado, então não seria o caso de falar em "fugir do padrão".

Imagino que isto já tenha sido discutido no grande meta, mas preferi fazer por aqui, para trazer a discussão pra nós (e pra fechar o ciclo dos posts sobre tachado).

Comment: Por um breve momento achei que era o terceiro post do mesmo assunto em menos de 24h

Comment: @Math tentei afunilar as dúvidas para o problema certo.

Comment: apoiado +1, vamos ganhar o recurso no cansaço...rsrssr

Comment: @Bacco entendi, faz sentido.

Comment: @SneepSNinjA duvido um bocado que se adote uma mudança tão profunda partindo de um "site filho", só quis dar um novo enfoque no assunto. Mas eu realmente sinto falta do tachado "fácil". Outra coisa que eu gostaria é de `*negrito*` e `_italico_`, acho muito mais intuitivo e elegante do que  __ e ** serem negrito, e o _ com * serem o itálico. Mas isso eu sei que é praticamente impossível.

Comment: Também duvido primeiro porque qualquer que seja o novo-recurso demanda custo, e se não houver retorno sobre o custo, dificilmente irá sair da vontade para a realidade